# Consulta SQL días , horas y minutos sumando registros Date time

Tags: sql, sql-server

quisiera saber si es posible formular una consulta SQL de estas características tengo esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
SELECT SUM((DATEPART(hh, CONVERT(TIME, AppTickets.FechaDeCierre))*60 + DATEPART(mi, CONVERT(time, AppTickets.FechaDeCierre)))*60+ DATEPART(SS, CONVERT(time, AppTickets.FechaDeCierre)))/60/60  AS [Suma de Tiempo Total Hr]
FROM dbo.AppTickets
```

Y quiero esto :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**lo que necesito es sumar fechas datetime y mostrar este formato :
17 Dias 10 Horas Y 20 Minutos en una sola columna.**

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Para obtener la cantidad días , horas y minutos necesitas dos fechas, inicio y fin, en el  select solo veo una fecha !!,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para obtener la cantidad de días, horas y minutos necesitas comparar dos fechas. Podrías hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
DECLARE @FechaInicio VARCHAR(50)= '28/11/2021 08:00:00';
DECLARE @FechaCierre VARCHAR(50)= GETDATE();
        
SELECT (DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@FechaInicio, @FechaCierre) / 1440) as Dias ,
        ((DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@FechaInicio, @FechaCierre) -
        (DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@FechaInicio, @FechaCierre) / 1440) * 1440)/60)  as Horas,
        ((DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@FechaInicio, @FechaCierre))  -
        (DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@FechaInicio, @FechaCierre) / 1440) *1440) -
        ((DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@FechaInicio, @FechaCierre) -
        (DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@FechaInicio, @FechaCierre) / 1440) * 1440)/60) *60  as Minutos
```

El resultado(al momento de la ejecución):

```
Dias        Horas       Minutos
----------- ----------- -----------
3           7           28
```

Comment: Y como haría en el caso de que estas fechas estén almacenadas en registros y quiera tener esa salida pero con la suma de las fechas de los registros

Comment: incluye el código en tu SELECT.  Para reutilizar el código podrías hacer una función en donde le pases como parámetros las fechas.